# How to find the words in an utterance which were not identified by LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding

(New to LUIS)
Let us say, the intent is "getSports" and it identifies all the sports present in the phrase provided by the user.

```
"I play table-tennis, baseball, rugby, squash."

LUIS identifies following entities,
sport : table-tennis
sport : baseball
sport : squash
```

But due to certain reason (might not have been trained for it), it is not able to identify "rugby". Is there a possibility to get this unidentified text?

Comment: for the entities like "sport" - it would be the easiest to use List entity and add whole big list of sports including modifications of the same word/expression. If you use Simple entity than you have to teach LUIS each new value after it was used at least once.. But maybe your scenario is more complex - could you reveal more eventually?

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid : I have a different handling for scenarios when all the sports are identified by LUIS as compared to partial identification. I do not want to lose the data and wait until further training.

Comment: agree with @FerdinandFejskid, List entity would be a good and easy choice. no need to train each sport entity separately.